# JQuery: Editing a table on click a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="#cells">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            document.write('<tr>');
            for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                document.write('<td></td>');
            }
           document.write('</tr>');
        }
        $('#arrow').click(function(){
            $('#cells').empty();
            for(var k = 0; k < 2; k ++){
                $('#cells').append('<tr>');
                for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                    $('#cells').append('<td></td>');
                }
                $('#cells').append('</tr>');
            }
        });
    </script>
</table>
```

Okay.. I have the above code which works perfectly for the first 2 loops (a table appears with 2 rows and 9 columns)

but in the second 2 loops a table appears with one row and 18 columns..

I don't know how to fix this properly

Any idea would help.. thanks

Comment: You can't append only opening or closing tags with jQuery, you'll have to append the entire `"<tr>....</tr>"` string at once. Alternatively, you can first `.append("<tr></tr>")`, which returns the `<tr>` element, and then append the `<td></td>`s to *that* so the `td`s become children of the `tr`. See [doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for details.

Comment: And you have to change table id from `<table id="#cells">` to `<table id="cells">` for jQuery to find it

Comment: Why are you writing elements in that way?, it's very expensive

Comment: @Kenney Thank you.. I have understood what you said, I'll work on it.

Comment: @dexhering I am not "very" experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert `<tr></tr>` code together.

```
$('#arrow').click(function(){
    var str = '';
    $('#cells').empty();
    for(var k = 0; k < 4; k ++){
        str += '<tr>';
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            str += '<td></td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#cells').append(str);
});
```

Comment: You fixed it.. Thank you